# Build webservice for both website and app

Tags: php, android, web-services

I've developed an android app that interact with my database by using some php scripts (one for each function of my app) that returns a json object with response data.

Now i need to build up a website too that do the same tasks of my app, but i would fix up my server code. 
Should i  have to maintain my app php scripts separate from website scripts (i'm planning to use some php framework to develop it), or there's a different way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No! Same script will work for all platforms.
If you follow proper protocols you will be good :)

Use Rest Console or similar tools to test your webservice on browser.
If you are able to get JSON response, then its good for all platform.

If you want to separate out the platforms and devices on server that can be handled by using user agent check at server end.

Comment: did I answered your question?